# How to insert an ASP.NET databinder inside a javascript src string?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, string, eval

How can you replace a selected string section of a javascript src?

I wish to insert this <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "YouTubeChannel")%> into the source string.

**ORIGINAL**

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=YourChannelName&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

**DESIRED**

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "YouTubeChannel")%>&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TwitterUser")%>"  data-widget-id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TwitterID")%>">
```

The < less than tag causes the script tag to close when the above code is used but work fine with anchors.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea. It's just like you were outputting a number in the middle of a string of text.

Though, you don't need the escaping quotes since the server will see the tag and output the value. The `<%#` essentially escapes it.

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "YouTubeChannel")%>&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

That should do it. Granted this does need to be contained in a data binded control.

Comment: Thanks steven I tried this first as it is how I would normally do it but the < causes the page to error when inside a script.

Comment: It cause the script tag to close. Total page failure.
I have anchor tags all over the page and they work fine. See edits above.